# Как проверить через PHP, установлен ли Flash?

Tags: flash, php

Есть возможность проверки через php, установлен ли у пользователя плагин flash, если да то подскажите, как проверить, а так же если у пользователя всё-таки не установлен флеш. Как отображать пользователю имеющуюся флеш анимацию просто как картинку. А то много жалоб, что ничего нет, ничего не происходит и сайт корявый.

Comment: Существовало бы в PHP - HTTP_USER_ACCEPT, тогда возможно было бы! А так коммент выше вполне подходящий!

Comment: Можете поставить сразу картинку и грузить поверх нее Flash. У кого установлен, тот увидит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напрямую через php вряд ли.
Могу посоветовать взять код, который Адобе встраивает в страницы, яваскрипт, он определяет наличие плагина и инициирует процесс установки. Например, [тут](http://oxanaratone.narod.ru/icons/bin-debug.zip).
Вам нужно будет послать свой запрос, в соответствии с результатом обнаружения.
Насколько понял, нужно получить результат вот этой функции - `swfobject.embedSWF()`.
Особо не силен в яваскрипте, поправите если что.

Answer (score 3):

Это есть во всех учебниках, и как правило, с этого начинают.

Сервер ничего не знает о клиенте, и знать собственно не обязан. Все данные о пользователе, тот сообщает сам, и некоторые данные измаются из параметров при подключении. Проще говоря все что прислали в заголовках, это есть правда, даже если это абсолютная не правда.

Я эту проблему решал так. Создавал iframe 0x0 px, и в нем флешка. JS обращался к ней, и если получали ответ, то ничего не делали, если ответ не получен, сообщаем клиенту.

Но php даже в этом случае ни сном ни духом, включен флеш или не включен.

swfobject.embedSWF() это вариант, но он не гарантирует что флеш работает 100%. Тут уже нужно исходя из ситуации решать.

Comment: Присоединяюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте JavaScript для этого. Я думаю, что напрямую через PHP, выйдет не легче, чем написать это на JS.

Answer (score 0):

используйте тег <noscript></noscript>