# Блок с заменой при отключенном flash

Tags: flash, javascript, html, php, css

Если у пользователя отключен флеш плагин, как вместо него загрузить блок div с каким-то контентом? В интернете нашел это чудо:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="img/header.swf" width="400" height="300">
     <param name="movie" value="img/header.swf" />
     <param name="quality" value="high" />
     <param name="menu" value="false" />
     <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
     <img src="/img/top.jpg" alt="Без флеша" height="300" width="400" /> 
    </object>
```

Можно ли этот код использовать, вообще подходит ли он для того, что я хочу, либо есть альтернативное решение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой [теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74884/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8-flash) я давал ссылку на [адобовский код](http://oxanaratone.narod.ru/icons/bin-debug.zip).
Как примерно работает:

```
// Метод замещает div#flashContent
// Если замещение неудачное то пользователь видит текст или ссылку (нужно добавить)
swfobject.embedSWF(
                "UTDSprite.swf", "flashContent", 
                "100%", "100%", 
                swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr, 
                flashvars, params, attributes);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent">
            <p>
                To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
                0.0.0 or greater is installed. 
            </p>
    </div>
```

Полноценный код в архиве.